# Matlab command window font size "function"

Tags: matlab, font-size

I wish to create a function to change the font size of command window of Matlab. I wondering about something like this:

> > ChangeFont(14)

... and "magicaly" the command window (and editor window, if possible) changes to a 14 pt font.

It's possible?

Comment: Does http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32005-cmdwintool work for you

Comment: One way is the following: "File > Preferences > Fonts > Custom" and there set your font and size. But it's not accessible setting from the commandline itsel so you would have to set it manually and afterwards disable it.